# SQL Trigger action based off comparing deleted and inserted value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have written an inventory application in C# and want to track changes to inventory quantity.  To that end, I have two tables: tblInventory and tblInvChange.  Currently I have an AFTER UPDATE Trigger which works great by adding the following to the tblInvChange: (using d. for Deleted and i. for inserted) d.lastphysical; i.lastphysical; d.quantity; i.quantity.

My problem is if, on the same date, I go back and change the quantity of an item I will get two records for the same date on the same item.  I would like to have the trigger insert a record into the tblInvChange table if the date does not exist and update a current record if it does.

```
    BEGIN
If(Select [fldlastPhysical] from deleted) <> (Select [fldLastPhysical] from inserted)

INSERT tblInvTracking(keyProductID, fldLocationId, fldLastPhysical, fldQuantity, fldInventoryChange, fldNewQuantity)
SELECT
   D.keyProductID, D.fldLocationID, D.fldLastPhysical, d.fldQuantity, i.fldLastPhysical, i.fldQuantity
FROM
   DELETED D JOIN INSERTED I ON D.keyProductID = I.keyProductID AND D.fldLocationID = I.fldLocationID;

Else

UPDATE tblInvTracking(keyProductID, fldLocationId, fldLastPhysical, fldQuantity, fldInventoryChange, fldNewQuantity)
SELECT
   D.keyProductID, D.fldLocationID, D.fldLastPhysical, d.fldQuantity, i.fldLastPhysical, i.fldQuantity
FROM
   DELETED D JOIN INSERTED I ON D.keyProductID = I.keyProductID AND D.fldLocationID = I.fldLocationID;

END
```

This was my understanding but does not work. An example on the correct way to accomplish this would be appreciated.

Comment: Dale, I was working with your example to ensure I could get it to work without additional comments.  You have been extremely helpful and I just returned to the site to accept your answer.  Note:  I'm not happy with people like Marc who critique a comment but provide not answers.  The sql-server tag had been there from the beginning.   What's his point?

Comment: And if you look at the edit history (click the "edited yesterday" link above my name) you will see that when you originally posted the question it didn't have the tag "SQL Server", that was added in a subsequent edit by "a_horse_with_no_name". SO is a very impersonal site, people are very matter of fact - best not to take it personally.

Comment: There is still one error I cannot figure out; Line 22 [Batch Start Line 6]
Operand data type date is invalid for add operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create 2 statements, an insert for records that don't exist and an update for records that exist. As best I can tell it would be something like the following, but this won't be 100% correct, you will need to work through the logic and make sure it matches what you are trying to achieve.

NOTE: This is assuming that `fldLastPhysical` is the date of interest, and that its a `date` not a `datetime`.

```
-- WHERE THE RECORD DOESN'T EXIST FOR THE GIVEN DATE - ADD A NEW ONE
INSERT tblInvTracking(keyProductID, fldLocationId, fldLastPhysical, fldQuantity, fldInventoryChange, fldNewQuantity)
    SELECT D.keyProductID, D.fldLocationID, D.fldLastPhysical, d.fldQuantity, i.fldLastPhysical, i.fldQuantity
    FROM DELETED D
    JOIN INSERTED I ON D.keyProductID = I.keyProductID AND D.fldLocationID = I.fldLocationID
    -- ONLY ADD A NEW RECORD FOR THIS DATE IF IT DOESN"T ALREADY EXIST
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM tblInvTracking T
      WHERE T.fldlastPhysical = D.fldLastPhysical
      AND T.keyProductID = D.keyProductID AND T.fldLocationID = D.fldLocationID
    );

-- WHERE THE RECORD EXISTS FOR THE GIVEN DATE - UPDATE EXISTING
UPDATE T SET
    fldQuantity = T.fldQuantity + X.fldQuantity
    -- It appears the following line is a datetime column, so you will need to determine what logic is required there - maybe just a straight update.
    , fldInventoryChange = X.fldInventoryChange
    , fldNewQuantity = T.fldNewQuantity + X.fldNewQuantity
FROM tblInvTracking T
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT D.keyProductID, D.fldLocationID, D.fldLastPhysical, d.fldQuantity, i.fldLastPhysical fldInventoryChange, i.fldQuantity fldNewQuantity
    FROM DELETED D
    JOIN INSERTED I ON D.keyProductID = I.keyProductID AND D.fldLocationID = I.fldLocationID
    -- ONLY ADD A NEW RECORD FOR THIS DATE IF IT DOESN"T ALREADY EXIST
    WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM tblInvTracking T
      WHERE T.fldlastPhysical = D.fldLastPhysical
      AND T.keyProductID = D.keyProductID AND T.fldLocationID = D.fldLocationID
    )
) X ON T.fldlastPhysical = X.fldLastPhysical AND T.keyProductID = X.keyProductID AND T.fldLocationID = X.fldLocationID
```

Comment: Dale, are you indicating that I don't need an IF Statement?  My fields are Date field.  You do have the logic correct.  I understand you have two statements, but don't you need logic?  Also, "SELECT 1 from...."?  Thanks.

Comment: @Charles - no you don't an `IF` - thats procedural logic, in SQL Server its better to use set based logic. Just put all you conditions in the `WHERE` clause. Potentially one of those statements won't affect any rows, but thats fine.

Comment: `select 1 from` is checking whether you already have a tracking record for that combination (product, location and date) which is what I understood from your question is what you wanted to do. But I could be wrong as your `IF` seemed to be comparing Inserted with Deleted.

Comment: You may need additional checks in the `WHERE` clause to check whether any of the values have changed.

Comment: I may still be missing something, but there is an error with the last line.  'The column fldLastPhysical was specified multiple times for X" .  I am still trying to understand what you have shown me but since you have been so helpful I went ahead and marked this answered.  Additional help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've fixed that but the logic isn't 100% correct since `fldInventoryChange` is a date, it shouldn't be being added together. But its not clear to me what should be happening there.

Comment: Dale, it looks like you edit and fixed the one error.  Now I have another.  "Operand data type date is invalid for operator".  This is in the update section.

Comment: Yes I explained that, I don't know what you want to do with the date, you can't add it obviously. This is where you have to define your logic for the update section.